# Where do AMP pages appear in Google search results?

Tags: amp-html, wizard, feed

:)

I am newbie to AMP, so please be patient. I am preparing my AMPlified version of a  website for first time.

1. Can you share: where will my AMP pages appear in Google search results? Only in news feed or in the whole search results list?
2. Will my website AMP pages links be available in google search results only when doing google search from mobile device or also when the search will be done over desktop PC for instance?
3. Is it worth for effort to AMPlify a multi-step form (something like web wizard)? Each step is loaded in different URL depending on the choices in the previous step, and some session variables and cookies are transferred between the steps (it is WordPress web)?

Thank you kindly, and once again, sorry if I ask stupid questions, but since I am at the beginning I would need guidance. I appreciate in advance your help!

Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your AMP pages will appear in Google search results on mobile just as your standard links appear in Google and in news feeds once Google has crawled and verified your AMP'd pages. AMP results have the little lightning bolt icon beside them.
2. AMP page links are only available in the Google search results (I think Bing may have finally adopted AMP as well, but that may be something I'm remembering wrong) on a mobile device. They do not show in the desktop search results. Your AMP URL will show up as https://www.google.ca/amp/s/www.yoursite.com/ (or whatever your region specific Google TLD is - .com, .ca, .au, etc.). If your site is up and running on AMP you can actually hit that link from desktop. For example the site I maintain would be https://www.google.ca/amp/s/www.craigattachments.com/.
3. I haven't dealt much with multi-step forms in AMP, our solution was to use amp-accordion (https://www.craigattachments.com/careers/employment-application/). This solution on AMP by Example may also work: https://ampbyexample.com/dynamic_amp/multi_page_flow/.

You said you're new to AMP, so this article may be helpful to you as well to help validate your AMP pages as you go in development so you don't have to wait until you upload: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/validate

Edit to point 2: They've recently updated the AMP URL structure to be this: https://yoursite-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/yoursite.com/ (ie; https://craigattachments-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/craigattachments.com/). Some search results still point to the old structure, but the new structure is slowly working its way in.

Comment: Thank you Craig! I am satisfied with your answer and suggested links. Hopefully this will not be so hard work... Still I have to learn it...

Comment: No problem! The website I linked that I maintain is built on WordPress as well (sounds like you're building on WordPress too), so if you have any questions I'm happy to answer them.

Comment: Well, since you offer, I need to ask something more :) Our WordPress+WooCommerce is on BlueHost, on shared hosting using BlueHost's WooCommerce hosting package and dedicated IP address. When we asked their team if we can implement AMP on our website, they answered that it is required VPS hosting (and not shared hosting). Do you have any clue why they say so? It is only html+css+javascript and what does the hosting have to deal with, according to this? What would happen if we implement AMP on BlueHost shared hosting?

Comment: I haven't heard of any mandatory reasons for needing to be on a VPS to make use of AMP. The main website I linked is on a VPS, but we did that before going to AMP as we were hitting a lot of technical limits set in place by the shared hosting plan - we use Dreamhost. I have another site I did in my free time, it's on shared hosting and using AMP on Dreamhost. Never had an issue. BlueHost is either (a) trying to get more money out of you or (b) worried about the resources you're currently using. I'd say AMP the site and if you have resource issues then decide if you need to move to a VPS.